# Unable to connect to SonarQube private IP with port 9000

Tags: azure, sonarqube, containers, sonarqube-scan

I am having some trouble and was needing some assistance.

I have set up a SonarQube instance on a machine in Azure, and I am trying to connect to it through its private IP address and port 9000. However, I am unable to connect and get a "connection timed out" error.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Checked the firewall rules: The firewall on the machine is not blocking incoming traffic on port 9000.

Checked the IP address: The private IP address of the machine is correct.

Checked the port: Port 9000 is the correct port for my SonarQube instance.

Checked the logs: There are no error messages related to the connection issue in the logs.

Restarted the SonarQube instance: Restarting the instance did not resolve the issue.

What else can I do to resolve this issue and connect to my SonarQube instance?

Note: I am using a Linux machine and bash commands.

Here is terraform code in case I did something incorrectly.

```
provider "azurerm" {
   features {}
}


locals {
  sonarqube_image_name = "sonarqube:9.9-community"
  sonarqube_container_name = "sonarqube-container"
  postgres_container_name = "postgres-container"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "examplegroup" {
  name     = "example-rg"
  location = "South Central US"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg-example-sonargroup" {
  name                = "nsg-example-sonargroup"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example-sonar-vnet" {
  name                = "example-sonar-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example-sonar-subnet" {
  name                 = "sonar-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example-sonar-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/16"] 

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "sonarqube" {
  name                = "sonarqube-group"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sonargroup.name
  ip_address_type     = "Private"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  subnet_ids          = [azurerm_subnet.example-sonar-subnet.id]

  container {
    name   = local.sonarqube_container_name
    image  = local.sonarqube_image_name
    cpu    = 1
    memory = 1.5

    ports {
      port = 9000
    }
    environment_variables = {
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://postgres-container:5432/sonarqube_db"
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME = "example_user"
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD = "example_password"
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = local.postgres_container_name
    image  = "postgres:11"
    cpu    = 1
    memory = 2
    ports {
      port = 5432
    }
    environment_variables = {
      POSTGRES_DB = "example_db"
      POSTGRES_USER = "example_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "example_password"
    }
  }
}

output "private_ip_address" {
  value = azurerm_container_group.sonarqube.ip_address
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially, I used the same code to create the container instance with virtual network.

**`test.tf`**

```
provider "azurerm" {
   features {}
}


locals {
  sonarqube_image_name = "sonarqube:9.9-community"
  sonarqube_container_name = "sonarqube-container"
  postgres_container_name = "postgres-container"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "examplegroup" {
  name     = "example1-rg"
  location = "EAST US"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg-example-sonargroup" {
  name                = "nsg-example-sonargroup"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example-sonar-vnet" {
  name                = "vt1231"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example-sonar-subnet" {
  name                 = "default"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example-sonar-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"] 

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "sonarqube" {
  name                = "sonarqube-group"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.examplegroup.name
  ip_address_type     = "Private"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  subnet_ids          = [azurerm_subnet.example-sonar-subnet.id]

  container {
    name   = local.sonarqube_container_name
    image  = local.sonarqube_image_name
    cpu    = 1
    memory = 1.5

    ports {
      port = 9000
    }
    environment_variables = {
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://postgres-container:5432/sonarqube_db"
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME = "example_user"
      SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD = "example_password"
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = local.postgres_container_name
    image  = "postgres:11"
    cpu    = 1
    memory = 2
    ports {
      port = 5432
    }
    environment_variables = {
      POSTGRES_DB = "example_db"
      POSTGRES_USER = "example_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "example_password"
    }
  }
}

output "private_ip_address" {
  value = azurerm_container_group.sonarqube.ip_address
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

[image]
Whenever we create an instance with private IP, we should be in the same network to access that instance as it is not publicly accessible.

I created virtual machine with virtual network same as created by SonarQube instance to connect SonarQube instance to accessing the private Ip with port 9000.

[image]

After creation, I connected the virtual machine through RDP and able to access the SonarQube instance through Private IP with port 9000.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Deploy container group to Azure virtual network - Azure Container Instances | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet)